# How can you create multiple folders with names that are altered versions of the names of existing files?

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have approximately 100 files with the file names such as: "1999 - Film Title.avi" & "2025 - Another Film Title.avi", etc. I would like each of these files to be moved to an individual folder with the folder name formatted like these examples: "Film Title (1999)" & "Another Film Title (2025)". Is such a thing possible, or will this be a laborious manual task?

I am using Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS).

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` ... Try this for a dry-run:

```bash
for f in *.avi
  do
    # Get the name part
    n="${f:7}"
    n="${n%%\.*}"
    # Get the year part
    y="${f:0:4}"
    # Define directory name
    d="${n} (${y})"
    # Create directory
    echo mkdir -pv -- "$d"
    # Move file into directory
    echo mv -nv -- "$f" "${d}/"
    done
```

If, the output sounds like what you want, then run this to do it for real:

```bash
for f in *.avi
  do
    n="${f:7}"
    n="${n%%\.*}"
    y="${f:0:4}"
    d="${n} (${y})"
    mkdir -pv -- "$d"
    mv -nv -- "$f" "${d}/"
    done
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks Raffa. It worked very well!